# I already installed mbstring but still get: "WARNING: Module php-mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

It all started when I wanted to install ***phpmyadmin*** in an **apache2** server on **Raspbian**, with **php7.3**.
And I got the following error when I went to "`localhost/phpmyadmin`":

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\mb_strpos() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:257 Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(208): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getArgSeparator() 
#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(171): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw(Array, '?')
#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(765): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommon(Array) 
#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(338): PhpMyAdmin\Core::linkURL('https://secure....') 
#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(367): PhpMyAdmin\Core::getPHPDocLink('book.mbstring.p...') 
#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(995): PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('mbstring') 
#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(110): PhpMyAdmin\Core::checkExtensions()
#7 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(23): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...') 
#8 {main} thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 257
```

Then, I installed ***mbstring*** through: `apt install php7.3-mbstring`.

But when I type "`a2enmod php-mbstring`" or "`phpenmod php-mbstring`", I get this on the console: `WARNING: Module php7.3-mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available`, however if I do an `ls` in that directory, I get this (mbstring.ini is inside of it):

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/php/7.3/mods-available# ls

calendar.ini  fileinfo.ini  iconv.ini     opcache.ini  posix.ini     sockets.ini  sysvshm.ini
ctype.ini     ftp.ini       json.ini      pdo.ini      readline.ini  sysvmsg.ini  tokenizer.ini
exif.ini      gettext.ini   mbstring.ini  phar.ini     shmop.ini     sysvsem.ini
```

---

**UPDATE**:

I just wrote: "`phpenmod -v 7.3 mbstring`" and solved the error.

I got information from the [link](https://tecadmin.net/enable-disable-php-modules-ubuntu/) CherryDT sent me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module is called `mbstring` and not `php-mbstring` or `php7.3-mbstring` (apparently you confused the names of the module and the package):

```php
phpenmod mbstring
```

More info [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/tecadmin.net/enable-disable-php-modules-ubuntu/%3famp).

Comment: This what I got when typed "`phpenmod mbstring`": `root@raspberrypi:~# phpenmod mbstring
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available`

Comment: You installed it only for PHP 7.3 so it cannot be enabled for the other versions if it's not installed for these too. Note that there is no more error about version 7.3 in your output, it should have worked now.